Error from server (NotFound): pods "texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx" not found
When I am using this command to tried to copy file from kubernetes pod to local machine:
kubectl exec texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx -- cat /app/profile.pdf > /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/profile.pdf

shows error:
Error from server (NotFound): pods "texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx" not found

I also tried to specify the namespaces like this:
➜  ~ kubectl exec texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx -- cat /app/profile.pdf > /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/profile.pdf -n reddwarf-pro
Error from server (NotFound): pods "texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx" not found

this is the get pods command look like:
➜  ~ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep texhub-server-service

reddwarf-pro       texhub-server-service-77b9c7c85d-zcmgx            1/1     Running   0              92m

why still shows could not found the pod even though the pod exists in kuberentes cluster? what should I do to fixed this issue?
